# Unable to download google data python library/ links on google sites documentation page not working

Tags: api, sites

I am unable to download the client library for java or for python. The link for python libs: 
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/downloads/list 
Also, The links 
https://developers.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/python_client_lib

and at developers.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/reference#Queries

and many other links on the documentation page of Google sites API aren't working. They return "page not found".

Is there a problem with my connection? 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I could download the python client library from  http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/downloads/list  just fine.

However the https://developers.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/python_client_lib  link is broken, "page not found" for me as well...

... however this link works: https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory

Maybe someone at Google just did an update?

You'll have to be more specific about which other links that aren't working.

Comment: please share that library with me, I still am unable to download it.

Comment: email me at fuzzyanalysis@gmail.com with the name of the file that you want and I will attach it in my reply.